# SharePoint 2010 : Custom Web part Assembly file missing

Tags: sharepoint-server, gac

SharePoint 2010 : Windows Server 2008 and We have few custom solutions deployed. Recently added a new WFE and re-deployed all solutions in the Farm. but in new WFE, few assemblies are missing and facing error with custom Web part that assembly is missing.

Tried re-deploying using PowerShell with GAC deployment, CA UI. Same error.

I could see the assemblies in old WFEs in installed Library, but could not locate the DLL file of the assembly while opening assembly in Windows Explorer view.

Is there a way to locate the DLL of an installed assembly or copy the installed assembly file directly to new WFE server.

Answer (score 0):

There should have been no need to redeploy. SharePoint would manage that itself for the farm solutions.

The only way I can imagine this broke is if there was an update for the webpart that removed dependencies from the wsp file. This could lead to a missing dll in the new server, since the new server will get the wsp and extract it locally.

Key question: Which DLL is missing? Was it listed as a requirement for the webpart in the documentation? (WSP with common, shared DLLs can cause other issues if you have the same dll in 2 WSP files for example)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Heiko-Hatzfed, missing assemblies are ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib  and one custom assembly. It was developed by a vendor long back, so we do not have the source code or DLL files. Also we could not locate the DLL of installed assembly in old WFE.

Comment: you have the wsp's for that webpart? Maybe there is more than one version of them? You can extract them and check the contents to see the DLLs

Comment: Yes, i have the latest version of wsp file. Extracted and checked, DLL is not part of it. Unfortunately we don't have the old versions of WSP file.

Comment: got the old version of the DLL in the GAC? extract it from the old server and manually deploy it onto the new one (via gacutil)... And make a note in the DR Documentation about it and document the manual change...

Comment: I see the assembly in the installed assembly library, but i could not find the DLL of that assembly in the GAC. I tried it via gacutil, command prompt but no luck.

Comment: use xcopy mydll*.dll c:\temp /s in the windows folder with the /s flag to copy it into temp so you can grab the file without the custom explorer plugin messing with you.